# Store switcher gives 404 error with customer logged in and folder structure in Base URL

Tags: magento2, multistore, customer-session, store-switcher

Did you ever face 404 Error when the customer is logged in and switching the store switch with having folder structure is Base Url?

Something like, Base Url is http://examplemagento.com/b2c/

I have noted that while switching the store it redirects to this controller `Magento\Store\Controller\Store\SwitchRequest.php`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just noted that, `Magento\Store\Model\StoreSwitcher\HashGenerator.php` model file is using `$urlParts = parse_url($targetUrl);` parse_url to get the base_url which will remove the folder from the actual base_url.

I just overrided `Magento\Store\Model\StoreSwitcher\HashGenerator.php` file and updated `$urlParts = parse_url($targetUrl);` line number 75.

1. Created preference in the `di.xml` file.

`<preference for="Magento\Store\Model\StoreSwitcher\HashGenerator" type="Custom\Module\Model\Rewrite\StoreSwitcher\HashGenerator" />`

2. Model overrided file as below.

   - Override `Magento\Store\Model\StoreSwitcher\HashGenerator` and just lines from line number 75 to 85 as below.

`$urlParts = parse_url($targetUrl);
//$host = $urlParts['host'];
//$scheme = $urlParts['scheme'];
$host = $targetStore->getBaseUrl();
$key = (string)$this->deploymentConfig->get(ConfigOptionsListConstants::CONFIG_PATH_CRYPT_KEY);
$timeStamp = time();
$fromStoreCode = $fromStore->getCode();
$data = implode(',', [$customerId, $timeStamp, $fromStoreCode]);
$signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $data, $key);
//$targetUrl = $scheme . "://" . $host . '/stores/store/switchrequest';
$targetUrl = $host . 'stores/store/switchrequest';`

Hopefully, it will do it the required changes.